# Simple proof of ownership of a password

Tags: password-based-encryption

I want to do a completely serverless p2p chat application on web browsers, so it won't even have a database to store accounts, but I still want to have some kind of identity system on it (an user can have a username on this chat that only they can use). To achieve this, I began to work on an authentication system a bit reminiscent of tripcodes, used on various imageboards (I don't know if this is really the way to go, I'm open for new suggestions):

- the user types a password,
- the application generates a public information (e.g. a hash or a public key) from this password using a one-way function,
- this public information is then converted to a human-meaningful identifier using systems like [tripphrases](http://worrydream.com/tripphrase/), [proquint](https://arxiv.org/html/0901.4016) or [identicons](https://github.com/drhus/awesome-identicons).

```
Examples:
"MyPassword" --(CRC32)--> "7d586a02" --(proquint)--> "hotig-muhig-donig-fubag"
"MyPassword" --(MD5)--> "48503dfd58720bd5ff35c102065a52d7" --(tripphrase)--> "interleave my calcifugous ghost"
```

The problem with using hashes as identifiers in a p2p system (i.e. with zero trust and no central source of truth) is that nothing prevents some user to write messages using whichever identifier they want while pretending that they obtained this identifier by hashing their password locally, like the protocol says. Thus, what I want is a way to prove the ownership of an identity without revealing the password. I can only think of one way to solve this problem:

- Alice types a password,
- the application derives a private/public key pair from this password,
- the public key is used to generate the human-meaningful identifier of Alice,
- Bob wants to verify the identity of Alice:

  - Bob sends a challenge (i.e. a random number) to Alice,
  - Alice encrypts the random number with her private key,
  - Alice sends the result back to Bob,
  - Bob decrypts the result using the public key of Alice (it can be obtained by converting Alice's identifier back to a public key),
  - if the decrypted number is the same than the one previously sent, then Alice indeed owns the password, otherwise Alice is lying on her identity.

But I would like to know if there is a simpler protocol than that to solve my problem. Preferably, I would like to avoid public-key cryptography altogether. As I'm doing this project just for fun, I don't really care about the following points:

- the strength of the passwords,
- if two users use the same password and hence get the same identifier,
- if other people know the hash or associated public key of a password, which clearly gives out information on the secret password, so a zero-knowledge proof is not necessary.

Any idea?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have no database to store accounts, how are you going to distinguish users? Suppose 2 users decided to have user name Alice. Bob established p2p connection with Alice. But how he knows which Alice it is?

Comment: In fact you can't directly chose your username, what you chose is your password, and it gets hashed and converted into a human-meaningful identifier. For example with tripphrases, you can get something funny like "behold my furious posterior". "Alice" and "Bob" are not usernames but people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a standard signature scheme. The user will type in a password, and receive their private key and associated username. Then, to post a message, they sign the message and broadcast the message, username, and signature. Other users will convert the username to a public key and then verify the signature.

This is the same way that bitcoin handles the identity crisis: tying messages to keys instead of real people.

Comment: That's a better way to handle the "identity crisis" (I like your phrasing) than my challenge system, but it still uses public-key cryptography, that I wanted to avoid for my project. But I'm not ontologically against it, so if I don't see a solution that doesn't use public keys I will accept your answer.

Comment: Can I know why you don't want to use public key cryptography? Signing is a cryptographic primitive after all.

Comment: It's quite slow (RSA and the like), let alone for a web browser, and I will use js-ipfs for the p2p communication, which already uses a private/public key pair and it would be redundant to have another one. I don't want to use the IPFS public key to generate the identifier, because this key only persists on one browser, so if you want to use your identity on another browser or computer, you have to transport you key on a USB stick or something like that.

Comment: Users aren't going to be posting messages faster than their device can sign them.  They won't even be able to hit the buttons on the screen fast enough. Most people also probably won't be reading messages faster than their device can verify. If someone wants to take their identity to a new device, they can enter their password again and get their private key right then and there.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just another thing, if an user has already signed a list of messages like "hello", "how are you?" and "goodbye", then an attacker could pretend that they are this user by using only signed messages like that. To prevent that, we could store the messages in a Merkel linked list (a bit like a blockchain), where a valid message signature is `encrypt(hash(message_content || previous_signature), private_key)`.

Comment: Ok but in your suggestion, the verifier has to find the last signature and somehow ensure that it is also valid, which requires checking its last signature and so on all the way to the original message. I heard there's a protocol where you only need to check the last message, as opposed to all of them. However, including a timestamp in the message would work decently.

Comment: Time agreement between all the nodes and causal ordering of the messages in a distributed system is far from trivial, so if you remember the name of the protocol you're talking about I'm very interested. But besides, I don't think it's always necessary to check all the signatures every time in my protocol, if we've accepted a message it means that we already checked its signature so we don't have to check in again for the following messages.

Comment: If I have 1000 messages and you're a new user and you want to verify my 1000th signature, you'd have to find my 999th signature and verify it which requires the 998th signature and so on, all the way back to the original.

Comment: I thought you'd have some central server receiving and storing messages which could also give timestamps, but it looks like I was mistaken. Anyways, the protocol is recursive zero knowledge, but someone else very briefly mentioned it to me and I never looked into it.